# Foreign key relationship issue

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have the following schema:

Companies

```
id (PK)
name
```

Users

```
id (PK)
name
dept_id (FK) // references id on Depts table
```

Depts

```
id (PK)
name
manager_id (FK) // references id on Users table
company_id (FK) // references id on companies table
```

Facts:

- A Dept belongs to a Company
- A Dept is managed by a User
- A User belongs to a Dept
- A User can manage multiple Depts

How can you create either a user record or dept record when both tables require a foreign key from the other table?

If I have a dept it must have a manager, but if I have a user they must be assigned to a dept. E.g if I try to create a user first the FK `dept_id` constraint fails because no `Dept` exist. If I try to create the `Dept` first the FK `manager_id` constraint fails because no user exists.

*** UPDATED ****

If some mapping tables were introduced, why would I need so many compound primary and foreign keys if the parent tables utilised unique id numbers as primary keys.

```
create table companies (
  id integer auto_inc primary key,
  company_name varchar(50) not null
);

create table departments (
  id integer auto_inc primary key
  company_id integer not null references id on companies
  dept_name varchar(50) not null
);

create table employees (
  id integer auto_inc primary key, 
  company_id integer not null references id on companies,
  emp_name varchar(50) not null,
  emp_num integer
);

create table managed_departments (
  company_id integer not null, 
  dept_id integer not null, 
  manager_id integer not null, 
  foreign key (company_id, dept_id) references departments,
  foreign key (manager_id) references employees (id),
  primary key (company_id, dept_id)
);

create table department_staff (
  company_id integer not null, 
  dept_id integer not null, 
  emp_id integer not null, 
  foreign key (company_id, dept_id) references managed_departments,
  foreign key (emp_id) references employees (id),
  primary key (company_id, dept_id, emp_id)
);
```

*** UPDATE ***

Schema translated into Laravel

```
 Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
 });

 Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
        $table->unique(['company_id','name']);
}); 

Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();

         $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
 });


  Schema::create('managed_departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->integer('department_id');
        $table->integer('manager_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->primary(['company_id','department_id']);

        $table->foreign(['company_id','department_id'])
              ->references(['company_id','department_id'])
              ->on('departments');

        $table->foreign(['company_id','manager_id'])
              ->references(['company_id','id'])
              ->on('employees');
 });

 Schema::create('department_staff', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->integer('department_id');
        $table->integer('employee_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->primary(['company_id','department_id', 'employee_id']);

        $table->foreign(['company_id','department_id'])
              ->references(['company_id','department_id'])
              ->on('managed_departments');

        $table->foreign(['company_id','employee_id'])
              ->references(['company_id','id'])
              ->on('employees');
 });
```

Comment: On phone so only comment but you could either allow `NULL` values in your FK columns (not so good option) or leave your FK in `Users` and create a mapping table for the `manager_id` from `Depts`.

Comment: Depending on your RDBMS you can make the foreign key not a constraint so FK existence isn't enforced. But you would want to add your own checks to make ensure referential integrity.

Comment: @JRLambert, a mapping table wouldn't necessarily enforce referential integrity either e.g. dept_managers (user_id, dept_id) would still mean I would have to do my own check. Just as easy to create a nullable FK on one of the tables but which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find yourself tied up in knots like this, you usually need more tables.

Companies is the easy part. I've omitted id numbers almost entirely for readability.

```
create table companies (
  company_name varchar(45) primary key
);

insert into companies values
('Vandelay, Inc'), ('Vertigenous, Inc');
```

Think of "departments" here as departments on an org chart. It's not the whole story.

```
create table departments (
  company_name varchar(45) not null references companies,
  dept_name varchar(30) not null,
  primary key (company_name, dept_name)
);

insert into departments values
('Vandelay, Inc', 'Human resources'), 
('Vertigenous, Inc', 'Personnel'),
('Vandelay, Inc', 'Information Technology'), 
('Vertigenous, Inc', 'Information Systems');
```

Companies need a few employees. Employees get an id number, because their names aren't necessarily unique within a company.

```
create table employees (
  company_name varchar(45) not null references companies,
  emp_id integer not null,
  emp_name varchar(25) not null,
  primary key (company_name, emp_id)
);

insert into employees values
('Vandelay, Inc', 1, 'Steven McGuire'), 
('Vertigenous, Inc', 1, 'Michael McDonald'),
('Vandelay, Inc', 2, 'Rosalie Jimenez'),
('Vandelay, Inc', 3, 'Phil Roberson'),
('Vandelay, Inc', 4, 'Sylvester Davis');
```

Departments in the real world (that is, as opposed to departments on an org chart) have a manager. Overlapping foreign key constraints guarantee that the manager and the department belong to the same company.

```
-- Assumes one current manager per department.
create table managed_departments (
  company_name varchar(45) not null,
  dept_name varchar(30) not null,
  foreign key (company_name, dept_name) references departments,
  manager_id integer not null,
  foreign key (company_name, manager_id) references employees (company_name, emp_id),
  primary key (company_name, dept_name)
);

insert into managed_departments values
('Vandelay, Inc', 'Human resources', 1),
('Vertigenous, Inc', 'Personnel', 1),
('Vandelay, Inc', 'Information Technology', 2);
```

To get work done, assign employees to a department. Again, overlapping foreign keys implement a business requirement--that the employee and the managed department belong to the same company.

```
create table department_staff (
  company_name varchar(45) not null,
  dept_name varchar(30) not null,
  foreign key (company_name, dept_name) references managed_departments,
  emp_id integer not null,
  foreign key (company_name, emp_id) references employees,
  primary key (company_name, dept_name, emp_id)
);


insert into department_staff values
('Vandelay, Inc', 'Human resources', 1),
('Vandelay, Inc', 'Information Technology', 2),
('Vandelay, Inc', 'Information Technology', 3),
('Vandelay, Inc', 'Information Technology', 4);
```

This allows an employee to be "in" more than one department, which is actually quite common in my experience. If you want each employee to be "in" only one department, add a constraint to the DDL for "department_staff".

```
unique (company_name, emp_id)
```

Comment: This is a very good explanation. However updating your answer to include  id numbers would have actually made more sense. I have one question though, why so many compound primary and foreign keys when an auto incrementing or unique id number would achieve the same - see my updated example code.

Comment: Also if an employee is only in one department then you could simply add a dept_id field to the employee table and get rid of the department_staff table entirely?

Comment: @ozzii: Look closer. Your code doesn't achieve the same. a) There's nothing wrong with compound keys. b) Your code allows, for companies, tuples like {1, Acme, Inc.}, {2, Acme, Inc.}, {3, Acme, Inc.}. c) Foreign key references must refer to columns that have some kind of unique constraint. d) Surrogate keys make every FK constraint equivalent to "on update cascade". That's not wise for *every* FK constraint. e) My code is standard SQL, tested in PostgreSQL. Your code won't run anywhere.

Comment: I see your point but when your building web applications for example with Laravel, eloquent relies heavily on surrogate keys. Plus as far as I'm aware there is no way to define a composite unique key such as `unique (company_name, emp_id)` in laravel?

Comment: You mention my code wouldn't run anywhere but i see no reason why it wouldn't work apart from the tuples - see schema translation into Laravel.

Comment: I've also fixed the tuples issue by introducing a unique composite key. Though I have to acknowledge you've provide an excellent explanation. Cheers.

Comment: *"You mention my code wouldn't run anywhere"* Yes, I said that. Paste your code as you originally wrote it into any SQL dbms engine. It won't run. It has syntax errors.